# Sending PIL Image over request in Python

Tags: python, python-requests, python-imaging-library

I have created a PIL Image and I want to send it to a server over requests.

My code looks like this, but I am not able to get it working as I get no errors.

```
import requests
from PIL import Image
from io import BytesIO

img = Image.new('RGB', (25, 25), color = (120, 120, 20))
byte_io = BytesIO()
img.save(byte_io, 'png')
byte_io.seek(0)

requests.post(
    url('/media/upload'),
    files={
        'files[]': (
            '1.png',
            byte_io,
            'multipart/form-data'
        )
    },
)
```

`print files` gives me `{'files[]': ('1.png', <_io.BytesIO object at 0x105b69290>, 'multipart/form-data')}` and it does not error out.

Comment: is it url('/media/upload') or rather url='/media/upload' ? if it is the first, how do you define the url function ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I got it working :)

My files object needed to look like:

```
'files[]': (
    '1.png',
    byte_io,
    'image/png'
)
```

Comment: This saved me literally hours of work. Kudos to you. (◠‿◠)